# "Subscribe for more and more video useful" is correct?

Tags: adjectives

I saw a sentence on youtube from a non-native English speaker. He said that:

**"Subscribe for more and more useful video".**

when I heard this sentence, I can understand that:

**"Subscribe for video which is more and more useful".** 
It sound "more and more" modifies "useful" ("more and more" functions as a adverb). It also meant **"we subscribe his chanel to receive videos, and his video become more and more useful day by day"**

But it's different from what the speaker really meant. I think he really meant that "We subscribe his chanel to receive useful videos, and useful videos will be uploaded more and more."

So can I rephrase his statement in two other ways following? Do you think thay are correct?:

**(1) "Subscribe for more and more video which is useful".**

**(2) "Subscribe for more and more video useful"**

**(3) "Subscribe for more and more video being useful"**

**(4) "Subscribe for more and more video to be useful"**

Comment: Perhaps you could supply a link to the video, and indicate the time that the statement occurs....

Answer (score 0):

I think that they just want you to subscribe so that you can receive more and more videos that are grammatically incorrect.

Comment: So how can we fix it grammatically correct?